# Calculating amount of infected in the background population?

Tags: prediction, epidemiology

I'm wondering if there's a method to calculate/predict the amount of infected in the population, knowing the R0, amounts of currently tested positive, amount of deaths, sensitivity of tests, incubation period and such?

Comment: Required reading (which gives examples of different approaches to answering your question): [Coronavirus: Why You Must Act Now](https://medium.com/@tomaspueyo/coronavirus-act-today-or-people-will-die-f4d3d9cd99ca)

Comment: Thanks, I had read that and been through the calculator, unfortunately it grossly underestimated the cases in my country. We have one death and it puts the true cases at 800, the same as the actually positively tested true cases in the country as of today.

Comment: There are *other* models in the linked articles. e.g., there are a range of values described by which confirmed cases underestimate not yet confirmed cases (i.e., pre-symptomatic). If I recall, there the more conservative end of that range was up at 32×confirmed cases.

Comment: Some problems with using R0 in more advanced outbreak/epidemic models is (a) it is not a fixed number, but an idealization based on an index case (who is an actual person with their own particular susceptibilities, vulnerabilities, resiliences, etc.), and (b) R0 as a concept is profoundly dependent on the particulars of the index case's individual qualities *within* an ecosystem. So you will want to think about model results (whichever model you are using) under a range of plausible R0 values (i.e. take a 'sensitivity analsys' approach).